# How to make chain transitions?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview

I have 40 UIView tile objects on the screen. Then in the view controller I have routine to flip those tiles using `transitionFromView` message. If I flip them at once in the loop, on the simulator it looks smooth, but on the iPhone it's struggling to flip them. That's because iPhone CPU/GPU is slower and can't handle so many transitions at a time. So what I want is to make some sort of chain transitions, eventually transitioning 5-10 at any given time. Each flip takes 0.4s now. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: There shouldn't be this problem. Once you've asked for an animation of 40 flipping views, it should be performed without difficulty. Perhaps you should show us your code? Maybe you're doing this wrong. Also, try it with Instruments; it will tell you where the problem really is.

Comment: Well, the code is pretty big and it won't be easy to trim it. It's not a problem also on > iPhone 4. But I've got to support 3GS as well. So I really need to chain that animations, it will also give some nice effect rather than all flip at once.

Comment: can you show the loop where you doing the transition

Comment: Try flipping them with Core Animation directly (see `CABasicAnimation`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably take the approach of just staggering the animation one for one.

Just maintain an `NSArray *views` with all of the views you're going to animate, and start the sequence with `[self transformViewAtIndex:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];`

```
- (void)transformViewAtIndex:(NSNumber *)index {
    // Make sure we're not out of bounds
    if ([index intValue] >= [views count]) return;

    // Get the view we want to work on
    UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex:[index intValue]];

    // Perform the animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{ // Whatever duration you want
        // ... This is where your actual transformation code goes
    }];

    // Schedule the next animation
    NSNumber *newIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[index intValue] + 1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(transformViewAtIndex:) withObject:newIndex afterDelay:0.2]; // Set delay to a number that is effective
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIView `transition...` animation method takes a `completion` block. There's your chain. Line up your blocks and set them as the completion blocks to the successive calls in the chain.

Or construct a grouped animation.